# what's the difference between "step" and "step into", while i use debug in bluej

Tags: java, debugging, bluej

When using debug in "blue j", it seems identical when I use the button of "step" or "step into", but what's difference between these two options?

Comment: FYI, this is common terminology used in many debuggers for many languages.  I've seen "step over" sometimes used for the first kind of step.

Comment: I gotta ask: did you read the bluej tutorial? It talks about the difference. If you did read it and didn't understand the distinction, it would help us to know what you didn't understand so that we can better tailor an answer. If you didn't read it... that should maybe have been your first step.

Answer (score 1):

The **Step** command will cause the running program to execute one statement.

The **Step Into** command will also cause the running program to execute one statement.
However, if the statement contains a method invocation, then the program execution will enter the called method and stops for further instruction.

You can refer to [this](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/02/BlueJ/BlueJ3.html) manual on BlueJ, the concepts are explained pretty neatly.

Answer (score 1):

step will go to the next line; where as stepinto will go into the method of the current line

example
1  obj.setNext(obj2)
2  System.out.println("Hi");

if I did step at line 1 it will go to line 2 in debug, if I did step into on line 1 it will go to the class file of obj and find the method setNext